# Is there a name for a set of numbers that equally surround another number?

Tags: terminology

This has to do with web page pagination, let's say there are a lot of pages (e.g. 100) and you're on page 35 and the pagination links at the bottom of the page show:

prev | 32 | 33 | 34 | **35** | 36 | 37 | 38 | next

So three pages on either side of the page you're on, is there a specific mathematical term to describe a set of numbers like that? So far I'm calling them 'neighbors' but I just wanted to check if there was an official name.

thanks!

Comment: *Interval* is often used. Maybe you are interested only in *symmetric intervals*.

Comment: NY Times mentions "location numbers": http://pogue.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/02/08/page-numbers-for-kindle-books-an-imperfect-solution/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *interval* is often used.  For the type of interval explicitly mentioned in the post, one could specify *interval symmetric about* $35$.